# how to use custom component in fragment xml?

Tags: android, fragment, components

how to use below component in fragment?
https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/Android-CircleMenu

Comment: The same way you would any other `View` in a `Fragment`. What specific problems are you having?

Comment: can you more explain about this?

Comment: I used this component in Activity, but when I tried to use it in fragment, I got into trouble.

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the code you're having issues with, and describe exactly what is wrong, including any error messages you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

The source code you linked to includes this line in `onLayout()`:

```
float angleDelay = 360 / (getChildCount() - 1);
```

Chances are very good that you've provided only one child:

```
float angleDelay = 360 / (getChildCount() - 1);

                 = 360 / (1 - 1);

                 = 360 / 0;
```

This will result in an `ArithmeticException` being thrown.

In the library's sample, they write:

```
mCircleMenuLayout.setMenuItemIconsAndTexts(mItemImgs, mItemTexts);
```

Make sure that each of these arrays has at least two elements.